# Qual é a diferença da implementação de classes em C++ e PHP?

Tags: php, c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou trabalhando atualmente em PHP e percebi que na hora de implementar classes eu não posso apenas instanciar e depois implementar abaixo da classe usando o seletor de escopo `::`.

Exemplo:

```
class Lista{
public:

    Lista(){
        first = last = NULL;
    }
    bool listaVazia();
    void inserirInicio(int valor);
private:
     No *first, *last;
};
```

Método:

```
void Lista::inserirInicio(int valor){
    first = new No(valor,first);
    if(last == NULL){
        last = first;
    }
}
```

No PHP eu não consigo fazer isso desta forma, só consigo resolver a função dentro da classe.

Comment: Mas o que você quer saber especificamente? Se isto está correto? Se pode colocar a implementação do método fora da classe?

Comment: isto, porque no C++ eu crio um `header.h` e defino a classe e os metodos, e no arquivo `function.cpp` eu escrevo o que os metodos vão fazer, me parece uma forma mais limpa, então não da pra  fazer desta forma ? qual é a vantagem e desvantagem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em condições normais o PHP funciona assim mesmo. Só é possível definir o método junto da sua declaração. Ao contrário do C++, declaração e definição do método (como é implementado) ocorre em uma só etapa, o que costuma ser mais conveniente. Em muitos raros casos separar pode ter uma pequena vantagem.

Então o C++ usa esta forma mais por limitação do que por vantagem. O C era assim. No passado os compiladores tinham que ter seu trabalho facilitado, os computadores não podiam lidar com grandes quantidades de texto e não podiam se dar ao luxo de facilitar muito o trabalho do programador.

Até existe como manipular as classes em PHP depois que elas foram declaradas e definidas mas não é comum fazer isto e é tão complicado que jamais será útil como forma de organização tanto que a sintaxe oficial não permite, a manipulação ocorreria em um nível mais baixo, então podemos dizer que não pode, e mesmo esta forma não atende o que você deseja. Mas não há nenhuma dificuldade em usar desta forma.

Sem me preocupar com um código correto, a grosso modo seu código ficaria assim em PHP:

```
class Lista { 
    private $first = null; 
    private $last = null;
    function inserirInicio($valor) { 
        $first = new No($valor, $first);
        if ($last == null) {
            $last = $first;
        }
    } 
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/ClassExample.php).

O compilador/interpretador trabalha em dois passos então ele primeiro analisa a estrutura de dados e depois analisa a implementação, o que facilita a organização do código e evita a necessidade das chamadas [*forward declarations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

Quem vem do C++ pode achar que isto é desorganizado, mas praticamente todo mundo que está acostumado com os métodos dentro da classe, acham o oposto. Não faz sentido ter a implementação fora, praticamente não há ganho. Claro que é possível usar algumas maneiras criativas de compilar a aplicação com a implementação separada mas não costuma ser uma boa ideia, tanto que é bem raro ver alguém fazendo isto. Em essência achar que um é mais organizado que outro é gosto. Eu acho que tudo junto é mais organizado. As linguagens que vieram depois do C++ tiveram a oportunidade de refletir sobre isto e todas conhecidas que não tinham nenhum legado para sustentar preferiram juntar a declaração e a definição do método em uma unidade.

A ideia das classes é justamente colocar o comportamento (métodos) perto do estado (variáveis). Ninguém disse que a implementação do comportamento deve estar presente junto mas é de se esperar que sim.

No comentário fala no uso do arquivo de cabeçalho, esta é outra separação independente de separar a declaração da definição. Claro que se essas duas não estivessem separadas não seria possível separar em dois arquivos diferentes. Nem sempre é possível separar a implementação. Quando usa-se `template` a implementação precisa estar disponível para o compilador então provavelmente ela estará no *header* também.

Trabalhe um tempo com uma linguagem decente que permite a definição junto da declaração e acho que você mudará de ideia que é mais limpo separar. Eu vejo minha produtividade ser maior por causa disto, eu entendo melhor os códigos quando está tudo junto. Você vai ter um monte de problemas com PHP e vai achar que a linguagem é uma porcaria, mas esses problemas não ocorrem porque a implementação está *inline*.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: O que será que está errado na resposta para receber um -1? É duro ter pessoas que sabem tanto mas não querem compartilhar o conhecimento com que deve estar escrevendo algo errado. Eu gostaria de aprender e não cometer o mesmo erro.

Comment: em resumo, uma boa pratica é implementar dentro da classe, o C/C++ realiza a declaração para depois fazer uma implementação não como forma de organização, mas sim como forma de  ajudar o compilador a entender quais metodos são referentes a tais classes

Comment: me questiono bastante disso pois o meu professor de ED1 diz que sempre devemos usar um `.h` para definição é um `.cpp` para desenvolver os metodos, vejo agora que  isto  vai de cada linguagem

Comment: É isto mesmo que você entendeu. E seu professor está certo. Para C++, usar o `.h`, ou `.hpp` como preferem alguns para diferenciar C++ de C, é o ideal para a **declaração**. Em raros casos ele não é necessário. Você está confundindo o termos. Definição é a implementação e vai no `.c` ou `.cpp`. Embora como eu disse acima, em alguns casos a definição pode ser necessária no *header*. Cada linguagem tem sua filosofia, não dá para aplicar os mesmos conceitos em todas as linguagens. Mas te garanto que se o C++ compilasse tudo junto, o *header* não seria útil para nada.