# Significado da terminologia "Orientado a objeto"

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

Qual é o termo correto para uma linguagem totalmente baseada em objetos (C#), e uma linguagem que usa objetos, mas não é completamente baseada neles.

Exemplo: O VB tem (tinha) diversas funções que não estavam em objetos, e um suporte (limitado) a OOP. Acho que o C++ é assim também. Existem termos certos para isso?

Eu me lembro de ver essa diferença de classificação (entre linguagens *object-enabled* [VB] e linguagens baseadas em objeto [C#]), mas não onde - nem quais eram os termos específicos.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Alerta**: vou fazer algumas simplificações e não vou seguir a definição estritamente acadêmica, muito menos de uma definição universal - **se é que existe**. Falarei do que todo programador deveria saber independente de gostar ou não da teoria. E se estiver errado (e não só simplificado), me corrijam.

## TL; DR

Eu não sei o que é. Ninguém sabe. Cada um diz saber e que os outros estão errados. Vou dizer o que eu acho.

O mais próximo de algo canônico é a [ISO/IEC 2382:2015, item 2122503](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:2382:ed-1:v1:en), mas é algo muito fraco.

## Introdução

Há uma confusão sobre vários termos. E é preciso olhar para o contexto para saber como definir. Não é possível dar uma definição sem saber exatamente do que está se falando. Corre-se o risco de dar a resposta certa para a pergunta errada. Então vamos por partes.

Obviamente não vou falar de objeto fora do contexto do desenvolvimento de software.

## O que é objeto e orientação a objeto

#### Objeto

O objeto é um conjunto de dados em algum local. Estes dados podem ser simples ou complexos. Tem uma resposta mais completa em [Em programação, o que é um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101).

Dentro de um código de um programa os objetos são representados por uma posição de memória e na maioria das vezes associados com identificadores, o qual chamamos de [variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) ou constantes. Existem objetos em outros contextos com outras características.

Não vou entrar em detalhes nas várias formas que estes objetos podem ser construídos mas obviamente eles possuem *byte(s)* que indicam uma informação básica entendida pelo processador ou pode ser um conjunto de dados em um nível mais abstrato que possuem uma relação direta e foram agrupados por algum propósito específico, formando um outro dado.

Podemos dizer que todas as linguagens de programação trabalham com objetos. Algumas praticamente não usam este termo na cultura de seus usuários, outras usam em situações específicas e outras usam com um significado especial.

#### Objetos como estruturas

É mais comum se referir a objeto como uma estrutura de dados complexa, em geral representada por uma `struct` (cada linguagem tem sua sintaxe) ou mesmo uma `class`. [Quando definimos essa estrutura estamos criando uma planta para o objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Em geral a ideia de classe surge quando se coloca comportamentos (funções) junto com estado (variáveis). É uma simplificação do que realmente é uma classe, mas é compreensível assim.

Note que, de verdade, um objeto não possui comportamentos (pelo menos não na maioria das linguagens que conhecemos). O dono do comportamento é a classe. O objeto é uma instância da classe e a instância acessa os comportamentos pré-definidos. Cada linguagem tem seu jeito de acessar.

Lembrando que algumas linguagens não trabalham com classes na definição que todo mundo conhece. Elas usam algum outro mecanismo que oferece resultado semelhante. Um deles é o [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42962/101), que nada mais é que um objeto sendo usado como modelo para criar outros. Em geral o comportamento está associado de alguma forma, mas dificilmente ele faz parte do objeto diretamente (já vi linguagem que faz isso, mas deve ser o motivo dela não ter sucesso :)).

Sabemos, é verdade, que algumas linguagens tratam os comportamentos (funções) como se fossem objetos. Não deixa de ser uma outra forma de usar o termo.

E aí chegamos nas linguagens orientadas a objeto. E temos uma [terminologia um tanto controversa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54310/101). A única coisa certa é que essas linguagens precisam facilitar a modelagem orientada a objeto, seja lá como isso é definido.

## Linguagens orientadas a objeto

Primeiro, é bom entender que o fato de uma linguagem ter classes ou alguma construção que funciona como se fosse uma, não quer dizer que a linguagem seja orientada a objeto. Costuma ser assim, mas ela por si só não define isso.

Outro ponto que usa-se para definir se a linguagem é OO ou não, é onde o objeto é usado na sintaxe. Priorizar o objeto quando se chama os comportamentos algumas vezes ajuda entender a linguagem como orientada a objeto. Então ter o objeto, a expressão que gera o objeto, ou a variável que "armazena" o objeto como o primeiro elemento de uma sintaxe que depois definirá o que será feito com o objeto ajuda a dizer que uma linguagem é orientada a objeto. Mas temos situações que chamamos o comportamento e passamos o objeto como ato secundário da sintaxe.

```
obj.Comportamento(); // OOP
Comportamento(obj); // não OOP
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/OopXProcedural.cs).

#### Encapsulamento

Não basta ter uma estrutura de dados que coloca próximo de si os comportamentos para dizer que há uma orientação para objetos. Isso lembra um pouco o encapsulamento (não é só isto), que é uma das características da programação orientada a objeto. Mas quase toda linguagem de programação permite alguma forma de encapsulamento hoje em dia.

Mesmo isso pode ser questionado. Em algumas linguagens [declara-se o comportamento junto à estrutura de dados, mas a sua definição é feita fora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53947/101). Então o comportamento ainda está próximo? Alguns dirão que sim e outros dirão que não, dependendo de como se define o que realmente é o comportamento, a sua intenção ou a real implementação.

Ainda que essa e outras características, que ainda vou citar, ajudem definir quando uma linguagem é orientada a objeto ou não, temos que olhar outras coisas.

Claro que se falamos em encapsulamento provavelmente devemos falar na possibilidade de definir níveis de acesso e visibilidade de partes do objeto ou seus comportamentos associados. Ter um `private` na linguagem é a parte mais visível do que é o encapsulamento, mas não é o encapsulamento em si, é *information hiding*.

Alguns dirão que [encapsulamento é mais que dizer que algo é privado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101) na classe. E até entendo que isso seja verdade, mas não define se a linguagem é orientada a objeto ou não. Essa definição se dará por uma característica concreta da linguagem. Afinal, encapsular filosoficamente, toda linguagem permite.

#### Herança

Depois vamos olhar para a herança e esta sim me parece ser mais definidora se uma linguagem é orientada a objeto ou não. Volto lembrar que existem algumas formas de fazer isso, e que algumas linguagens não possuem classes, mas podem se aproveitar de modelos de outros objetos para montar sua estrutura. Pelo menos isso é exclusivo de OOP.

A herança é responsável pela vantagem que mais é citada como argumento de venda do paradigma: o reuso de código.

Claro que o reuso pode ser obtido em outros paradigmas, mas a forma como se faz na herança simplifica e organiza de uma forma específica (ajuda em alguns pontos, atrapalha em outros). Hoje se dá o devido valor à herança, ou seja, pouco. Recomenda-se [preferir a composição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101).

Quando usamos um `extends` ou algo com a mesma funcionalidade, estamos vendo a superfície do que é a herança.

#### Polimorfismo

Também costuma-se dizer que ter um mecanismo específico de polimorfismo é necessário para a linguagem ser considerada orientada a objeto. Essa é uma característica que permite que um objeto substitua outro esperado.

Nas linguagens "mais orientadas a objeto" esse mecanismo é bem poderoso e flexível. Em outras, por pragmatismo, existem limitações.

É comum ter um `virtual` ou outra sintaxe (às vezes implícita) para indicar o que pode ser polimórfico. Mas isso apenas define um mecanismo. É possível fazê-lo manualmente, mas apenas mecanismos automáticos seriam considerados para a linguagem possuir característica de OO.

Manualmente você pode fazer qualquer coisa, até em Assembly. Outros mecanismos podem ser adotados, entre eles o polimorfismo paramétrico usando [genericidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101).

#### Abstração

Nem todas as definições falam na [abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23103/101) mas é comum dizer que uma linguagem é OO só quando tem isto. E este termo é um pouco mais controverso porque muitas vezes obtém-se ela independente da linguagem oferecer algo específico. Tem a ver com o modelo.

Muitas vezes a abstração é obtida pelo simples fato de como se monta o programa. A abstração pode ser considerada como o ato de transformar elementos do mundo real para o código.

E aí mora um grande perigo, e por isso muita gente programa errado e abusa de OOP. É comum olharem para um objeto do mundo real e querer reproduzi-lo no código. Em geral não dá. Só é possível criar uma abstração do que é o objeto real. Você não constrói pessoas no código, apenas um objeto que representa uma pessoa. Parece óbvio, mas os programadores vivem tentando construir pessoas. Por isso é mais fácil usar OOP em *games* e GUI. O domínio já trabalha com abstrações bem definidas.

Algumas linguagens possuem mecanismos específicos que reduzem a complexidade e ajudam expressar melhor o objeto. Mas nem todas são OO. [`abstract`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101) ou [`interface`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/101) é só uma ponta e não define de fato o que é a abstração. Por isso o termo se aplica mais à modelagem do que à linguagem.

Alguns dizem que as outras características expostas acima e abaixo já dão a abstração necessária.

#### Mais características

Também fala-se em [sobrecarga de operadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61034/101). Isso está em algumas linguagens consideradas OO mas não em todas. Mesmo nessas, a implementação costuma ser limitada. Então algumas pessoas consideram que isso não é fundamental para a linguagem ser considerada OO.

Existem algumas outras definições, ou pelo menos detalhamentos destas definições apresentadas, que vão determinar se uma linguagem é orientada a objeto ou não.

## Quais linguagens são orientadas a objeto?

Se levar tudo a ferro e fogo, como foi definido por [quem criou o termo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Kay), só [Smalltalk](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) é realmente orientada a objeto. Claro que é um pouco de exagero. O que quero dizer é que a definição inicial do termo não leva em consideração essas coisas que foram mostradas acima. Pelo menos não desta forma.

De fato não conheço (não quer dizer que não exista) outra linguagem que seja puramente orientada a objeto. Tá bom, [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) e [Self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(programming_language)) também. As linguagens que conhecemos como sendo OO na verdade são multi-paradigmas. Até porque é algo mais pragmático. Coisas puras costumam ter pouco espaço para resolver "problemas reais", ainda que isto não signifique que a linguagem não seja boa e não consiga resolver qualquer problema que outras linguagens resolvem.

O próprio Alan Kay disse que Lisp é mais OO que Smalltalk. Bom, Lisp é mais qualquer coisa, é uma linguagem aberta que pode ser qualquer coisa, por isso "ninguém" usa.

Na verdade até Smalltalk tem alguma coisa imperativa, puro mesmo não existe. É como água, sempre tem umas coisas extras na água, ela nunca é só H<sub>2</sub>O.

Mesmo a definição [do que é puramente orientado a objeto parece ser controverso](https://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs). Cada um garante que sua definição é a certa. É quase religioso.

## Manutenção do código

O pessoal diz que usa OOP para facilitar a manutenção. Ótimo motivo. Mas cada um tem seu jeito de ver como fazer isso.

Existe uma corrente que prega que tudo relacionado ao objeto deve estar junto dele. Outros dizem que tudo deve ser mais separado. Cada um entende isso como quer. E diz que os outros entendem errado.

Os que levam o encapsulamento a ferro e fogo não melhoram a manutenção. Desde os primórdios o que facilita o trabalho é **dividir e conquistar** e não agrupar. A divisão facilita criação e a mudança do código. Só deve estar junto o que é indivisível, o que é a mesma coisa.

Óbvio que tem quem divida demais e tem quem junta demais. Isso é quase uma arte. É parecido com interpretação de texto. Cada um pode interpretar como quiser, mas o que o texto fala de fato é que importa.

Eu vejo algumas pessoas que se acham donos da verdade nesse assunto que modelam coisas de forma [acoplada e não coesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) "porque OOP é assim".

Outras pregam a forma mais separada, e o que eles fazem de fato é a modularização, mesmo que chamem de OOP. Não confio em quem nem consegue adotar uma definição correta, em quem inventa um termo novo para o que já existe.

#### [Modularização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101)

Ainda que eu discorde com a forma como eles fazem, de fato a modularização é fundamental para melhorar a manutenção do código.

Se as pessoas entenderem bem o que é o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), provavelmente não precisa de qualquer outra coisa. Isso simplifica a manutenção, junta o que deve ser junto e separa o que deve ser separado. O que importa é ter uma forma canônica de algo. Isso facilita a manutenção. Veja também [O que são os conceitos de coesão e acoplamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Claro que sempre haverá discordância entre o que é divisível e o que não é. Um exemplo que eu uso muito:

Tem quem ache que um cliente ou um fornecedor devem ter tudo o que se refere a isso, ou seja deve ter todos os dados da entidade que exerce esse papel. Pra mim esses são [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) que pessoas podem exercer, são coisas muito distintas. Quando faz isso você passa ter dois objetos que representam a mesma pessoa. É muito errado. Isso acopla, tira a coesão e dificulta a manutenção.

Quando a pessoa entende como dividir as coisas ela percebe que [o modelo relacional não é tão ruim assim e que as classes podem não ter tanta impedância com o banco de dados quanto elas acreditam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101). E param com o *non-sense* de [usar NoSQL onde não cabe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101).

Pra mim quem acha que OOP é o oposto da modularização não quer manutenção facilitada de verdade. Quem acha que OOP é modularização deveria usar o termo correto. Quem acha que OOP é modularização mais alguma coisa então deveria mostrar isso, não vejo ninguém fazendo. Quem só é papagaio não merece credibilidade.

#### *Design patterns* e princípios como o SOLID

Curiosamente a maioria dos padrões de projeto e o próprio SOLID pregam coisas que vão contra o que muitos dizem ser OOP. Eu prefiro essas coisas do que OOP. Essas coisas ajudam a manutenção se usadas onde deve. Mas eu acho que essas coisas tem a ver com modularização.

#### Marketing

Claro que o termo ficou conhecido porque outras linguagens que não foram tão a fundo e começaram ter estas características adicionalmente. Dando nome aos bois, C++ foi a linguagem que tornou o termo como algo "da moda" ([Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) deu a ideia do OOP que ela usa).

Pela definição original C++ não é uma linguagem orientada a objeto. Objetos não são de primeira classe, nem tudo na linguagem é um objeto, e existem mecanismos que subvertem a orientação a objeto.

Note que C++ é uma linguagem essencialmente imperativa com várias outras características, entre elas, OOP, funcional e meta-programação. O grosso do que se faz nesta linguagem é imperativo. Ponto.

Não é só em C++ que OOP é um [paradigma secundário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101), essencialmente o é em todas as linguagens.

Em C++ funções ou métodos não são objetos (hoje até pode ser). Classes não são objetos. Várias construções não são objetos.

Mesmo quando falamos apenas em tipos, nem todo tipo de dado deriva de um tipo principal.

Aqui entramos em outra questão. Todo tipo de construção da linguagem precisa ser um objeto para ser considera OO? Ou todo tipo de dados deve ser derivado de um tipo principal chamado `Object`?

Aí começamos entrar no *marketing*. Algumas linguagens, não só C++, mas também C#, Java, Ruby, e outras, cada uma do seu jeito, gostam de vender a ideia que são orientadas a objeto e cada uma puxa a sardinha para o seu lado dizendo que ela é OO por causa disso ou daquilo. E tentam desqualificar as outras. Claro que a pequena comunidade de Smalltalk faz o mesmo com todas. Isso ocorre porque os "programadores" começaram achar que OO é a oitava maravilha do mundo, então toda linguagem "precisa" ser OO. Apenas uma minoria entende que é só **mais** uma ferramenta.

Claro que todas essas linguagens são orientadas a objeto. **Em parte**. Nenhuma delas tem todas construções como objeto. "Nenhuma" tem [troca de mensagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86479/101) como definido originalmente. Eu poderia achar um monte de coisas que mostram que essas linguagens não são orientadas a objeto. Mas quase todo mundo diz que elas são. As pessoas vão adaptando a definição para que elas se encaixem. Claro que a maioria repete o que ouviram sem questionar.

C++ e Java sequer tem todos os tipos derivados de um tipo único. C# e Ruby possuem isso (só estou ficando nestes exemplos, mas outras linguagens poderiam ser citadas). Daí vem a expressão "tudo é objeto". Alguns entendem que está se falando do tipo `Object`. Outros, poucos, entendem que é tudo mesmo, não só tipos de dados. Há controvérsias se é necessário todos os tipos derivarem do mesmo tipo para ser orientada a objeto.

E muitos consideram C++ e Java como os melhores exemplos de linguagens OO. Vai dizer que elas estão erradas. Melhor não, aceite que tem um fundo de verdade nisso, mesmo que elas não tenham ideia do que estão falando.

Pode-se [programar OO em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80228/101) mas a linguagem não ajuda. Então C não é uma linguagem OO. Mas qualquer linguagem pode ser usada para programar em cima de um modelo orientado a objeto, até Assembly.

O fato da linguagem permitir outros paradigmas indica apenas que ela não é pura.

A briga para saber qual linguagem é mais orientada a objeto é uma grande perda de tempo.

E as linguagens estão colocando cada vez mais *features* que fazem o código fugir de OO.

## Conclusão

Então pode-se dizer que toda linguagem tem suporte a objeto, mesmo as mais arcaicas. Algumas permitem criar ou simular classes, então algumas linguagens se acham mais no direito de dizer que são orientadas a objeto quando não são.

Algumas possuem mecanismos próprios que facilitam e incentivam o encapsulamento, herança e polimorfismo e são, a grosso modo, orientadas a objeto de fato.

E ainda existem linguagens pouco conhecidas que são puramente orientadas a objeto. Seguem todos os preceitos do paradigma e não usam outros paradigmas para facilitar o que este paradigma não funciona bem (ainda que mesmo isto possa ser questionado).

De fato a conclusão do AP em sua resposta é correta e neste caso não deve se prender demais ao termos, não vale querer impor uma definição e ver o que é ou não é. Desde que não prejudique o uso ou a comunicação dos programadores, vamos aceitar o termo que a comunidade de cada linguagem usa dentro de seu contexto. Questionar é importante, mas não vale esforço maior para impor uma definição.

Já na pergunta tem algumas informações que não são comprovadas.

#### Me engana que eu gosto

Mas não se engane, a maioria dos programadores passam a **maior parte do tempo trabalhando em código imperativo** com características orientadas a objeto e que talvez a estrutura geral da aplicação tenha sido modelada usando este paradigma. Talvez o *design* tenha sido orientado a objeto. E geralmente mais modularizam que fazem OO.

É bom lembrar que o termo foi criado em uma época que muitos acreditavam seriamente que existia [bala de prata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), que a inteligência artificial resolveria tudo, e que o mundo do desenvolvimento de software seria um dia todo automatizado, onde os usuários programariam suas próprias necessidades. A parte boa é que caíram na real e de tudo isso sobrou algumas coisas úteis que se aplicam ao real processo de desenvolvimento de software.

E também não se engane, todos paradigmas exibem seus problemas. Escolher um paradigma é escolher com qual tipo de problema no desenvolvimento do software quer lidar. Não existe paradigma melhor. Tem alguns que se [adéquam melhor em cada tipo de trabalho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55493/101), e que uma pessoa ou equipe lida melhor com ele.

É claro que [as pessoas tendem a escolher um e tentam resolver tudo com ele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). Ou pelo menos com dois, já que a maioria acha que programa puramente orientado a objeto mas sempre usam o imperativo também. E aí é complicado porque se pessoas usam um paradigma e nem sabem, provavelmente usam o outro de forma errada e também não sabem. Alias, virou lugar comum sempre dizer que o outro não sabe usar OOP. Eu não sei mesmo, mas [pelo menos eu sei disso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) :P

A página da Wikipedia *linkada* na resposta do AP ajuda entender, mas tem muitas simplificações que ajudam perpetuar alguns mitos. Por isto eu comecei fazendo um alerta. Na versão em inglês que tem mais informação é até pior, porque compra outros mitos, como quais linguagens são orientada a objetos. O artigo compra o *marketing*.

No mundo ideal deveria ter mais termos para acomodar cada definição do que dizem ser orientação a objeto.

#### Conclusão da conclusão :)

Termos bons são os aceitos universalmente, que sobrevivem ao tempo e que são facilmente explicados.

Por isso que eu fico com os fundamentos, com a simplicidade, com o que é provado que funciona.

E aceito a ideia que qualquer ferramenta usada do jeito certo funciona e todas usadas de forma errada servem para nada.

Quando as pessoas sequer sabem o que é a ferramenta não tem como usar certo.

Leitura adicional:

- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101)

> Tendo feedback, eu melhoro

Answer (score 3):

Aqui podemos ver os termos para as duas classificações, assim como uma explicação: [Orientação a objeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos)

Linguagens **orientadas a objetos** usam objetos internamente para representar os elementos que constituem a própria plataforma (variáveis, métodos, ambiente).

Em linguagens **orientadas a objetos puras**, tudo na linguagem é um objeto.

Linguagens **com suporte a objeto** permitem o uso de objeto, em maior ou menor grau (com ou sem herança, por exemplo), mas expõe uma parte ou toda sua funcionalidade sem encapsulá-la em objetos.

Por exemplo VBA, que permite utilização de objetos, mas expõe várias funções sem encapsular em objetos (InStr(), Mid(), etc.). Os tipos básicos também não são objetos.

Não sei se existe uma linha precisa que delimita cada conceito, possivelmente é mais qualitativo.