# Diferença entre Objeto e Instância

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia

Em programação orientada a objetos muito se fala tanto em instâncias de classes como em objetos. Buscando o significado de cada um, percebi que ora os conceitos se unificam e os mesmos são tratados como sinônimos, ora os conceitos se diferenciam e os mesmos são tratados de forma distinta.

Própria página da Wikipedia mostra essa confusão: na definição de [instância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inst%C3%A2ncia_(classe)) traz que é "um objeto cujo comportamento e estado são definidos pela classe"; já na definição de [objeto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) traz que "objeto refere-se a uma instância de uma classe". A instância é um objeto e o objeto é uma instância? Então seriam a mesma coisa?

Em um [livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=_xv1frKVlp8C&pg=PA443&lpg=PA443&dq=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&source=bl&ots=fxUi_Wf2PH&sig=QA3-7C8T3sUUHWHouXQ2HonQhls&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&f=false) sobre orientação a objetos há a definição para objeto:

> Objeto (também conhecido como instância de objeto ou instância) é uma instância individual da estrutura de dados definida pela classe.

O que dá a entender que os conceitos de objeto e instância são os mesmos.

Por sua vez, nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88685/5878) sobre o significado de "orientado a objetos", é citado:

> O objeto é uma instância da classe e a instância acessa os comportamentos pré-definidos.

Dando a entender que o objeto é uma instância, mas os conceitos não são equivalentes, dado que seria a instância responsável pelo acesso aos comportamentos da classe.

Então, ao final, instância e objeto são sinônimos ou são coisas diferentes mas que são diretamente relacionadas entre si ao ponto de comumente serem consideradas equivalentes?

---

Outras referências:

- [(1)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=OD24CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&dq=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&f=false) "*Na OOP uma instância de uma classe é chamada de objeto*".
- [(2)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=H8A0lZtqaXsC&pg=PA245&dq=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&f=false) "*Cada elemento de uma classe é conhecido como objeto ou instância dessa classe*".
- [(3)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=H8A0lZtqaXsC&pg=PA245&dq=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20inst%C3%A2ncia&f=false) "*MARTIN 1994: Um objeto é uma instância de um tipo de objeto*".
- [(4)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=carqdIdfVlYC&pg=PA352&dq=OOP%20instance%20terminology&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20instance%20terminology&f=false) "*Instance: An individual object of a certain class*".
- [(5)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=carqdIdfVlYC&pg=PA352&dq=OOP%20instance%20terminology&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20instance%20terminology&f=false) "*Object: A unique instance of a data structure that's defined by its class*".
- [(6)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=yy2qKCf2_UYC&pg=PA525&dq=OOP%20instance%20terminology&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20instance%20terminology&f=false) "*[...] an object represents an instance*".
- [(7)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=o_q5BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA552&dq=OOP%20instance%20terminology&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=OOP%20instance%20terminology&f=false) "*[..] objects are instantiated from a class, and each object is referred to as an instance of the class*".

Comment: An individual object of a certain class = 1 unico item de uma classe...

se tenho um grupo de pessoas... o objeto é as pessoas... e a instancia é Daniel... Anderson... Joao... instancia é  1 unico objeto criado da classe...
se tenho 10 pés de limao ... o objeto é o pé de limão, e cada pé de limao é uma instancia do tipo pé de limão

Nao que são iguais, objeto se refere como o todo e instancia é especificamente onde  aquela classe, aquele objeto aparece... exemplo basico seria assim: 
Model model; Model = objeto  e model = instancia da classe Model

Comment: Em programação, ou em programas, seria algo assim:
Objecto -> propriedades caracterizadoras.
Instância -> Existência, ou mesmo a forma materializada.
Cor de um carro, Tipo de Motor, Número de Rodas  seriam basicamente o objecto em si, e "Um Carro" seria uma instância desse objecto.

Comment: Nessa frase que o AP citou não entendi onde está a diferença entre os dois: "O objeto é uma instância da classe e a instância acessa os comportamentos pré-definidos". Se um objeto é uma instância como afirma a frase, pode-se substituir instância por objeto e assim fica "o objeto acessa os comportamentos pré-definidos". Nenhuma diferenciação aqui.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A sua referência 3 é uma definição super precisa e correta:

> *"Um objeto é uma instância de um tipo de objeto"*.

Vê-se logo que instância é a coisa técnica que permite a existência de um objeto na memória. A palavra Objeto, por sua vez, pode ser usada num nível mais alto de abstração.

Veja: a palavra *"objeto"* existe porque o conceito da Orientação a Objetos é representar no software as características e comportamentos relevantes dos objetos reais do domínio.

Então ao modelar um sistema de notas fiscais, as notas e seus itens são **objetos**; e ao codificar o sistema, **classes** serão declaradas para definir estes objetos, e para que estes objetos existam na memória serão criadas **instâncias** destas classes.

```
class NotaFiscal; // não é objeto nem instância, é a definição de um objeto.
var notaFiscal = new NotaFiscal; // "notaFiscal" referencia uma instância
notaFiscal.setNumero(1234);      // a instância representa a Nota Fiscal 1234, 
                                 // que é um objeto de domínio 
                                 // e existe como objeto para além do código fonte.
```

Depois de os objetos serem persistidos as instâncias são removidas da memória e os objetos como os conhecemos no mundo real estarão seguros na base de dados até que precisemos lidar com eles novamente - e daí novamente vamos criar instâncias das suas classes para poder olhar para estes belos objetos e manipulá-los.

E se os objetos forem persistidos num banco de dados orientado a objetos, os objetos continuam a existir no âmbito técnico além do conceitual mesmo depois de suas instâncias não existirem mais na memória.

Por fim, **instância e objeto são sim termos intercambiáveis**, como neste diálogo hipotético mas correto:

> _ Recuperei todas as notas fiscais da base e fiquei com este array de 1000 objetos.
>
> _ Seria melhor não ter tantas instâncias de uma vez na memória pois senão o sistema vai ficar lento, já que Nota Fiscal é um tipo de objeto grande.
>
> _ Ok. Então vou fazer uma paginação para manter apenas 10 objetos de cada vez no array.

Comment: Boa resposta, só achei um pouco confuso dizer que os objetos são persistidos quando na verdade o que é persistido é apenas o estado dos mesmos (considerando que objetos são compostos de estado + comportamento).

Comment: @Piovezan não discordo de você, esta é uma maneira de dizer também. Dizer que o próprio objeto está persistido é uma expressão de mais alto nível de abstração. E se persistimos o estado do objeto com o fim de poder reconstituir o objeto em memória mais tarde novamente, então não faz muita diferença se dizemos que é o objeto ou se dizemos que é o estado dele que está persistido.

Answer (score 11):

Você tem uma classe A que pode ser instanciada n vezes, gerando um grupo de n objetos do tipo Classe A. Se você pegar um destes objetos, individualmente, você estará lidando com uma instância de A. As fontes, em sua grande maioria, realmente tratam objeto e instância de forma intercambiada. Tenha em mente que a instanciação de uma classe A dará origem a um objeto da mesma classe. (Sendo simplista aqui, ok? Descartando conceitos mais avançados como herança, polimorfismo, etc.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Então instância seria a abstração do objeto?

Comment: Eu prefiro pensar como instância sendo a "materialização" da classe, o que gera um objeto na memória. Algo com o qual você pode interagir. ;)

Answer (score 5):

> A instância é um objeto e o objeto é uma instância? Então seriam a
>   mesma coisa?

Sim e não.

Na própria página da Wikipedia há 3 parágrafos que falam a mesma coisa de formas diferentes. É redundante mas assim o fizeram para esclarecer melhor.

> As instâncias de uma classe compartilham o mesmo conjunto de
>   atributos, embora sejam diferentes quanto ao conteúdo desses
>   atributos. Por exemplo, a classe "Empregado" descreve os atributos
>   comuns a todas as instâncias da classe "Empregado". Os objetos dessa
>   classe podem ser semelhantes, mas variam em atributos tais como "nome"
>   e "salário". A descrição da classe contém os itens correspondentes a
>   esses atributos e define as operações ou ações relevantes para a
>   classe, tais como "aumento de salário" ou "mudança do número de
>   telefone". Pode-se então falar sobre uma instância com o nome = "Joana
>   Coelho" e outra com o nome = "João Coelho".
>
> Instância é a concretização de uma classe. Em termos intuitivos, uma
>   classe é como um "molde" que gera instâncias de um certo tipo; um
>   objeto é algo que existe fisicamente e que foi "moldado" na classe.
>
> Assim, em programação orientada a objetos, a palavra "instanciar"
>   significa criar. Quando falamos em "instanciar um objeto", criamos
>   fisicamente uma representação concreta da classe. Por exemplo:
>   "animal" é uma classe ou um molde; "cachorro" é uma instância de
>   "animal" e apesar de carregar todas as características do molde de
>   "animal", é completamente independente de outras instâncias de
>   "animal"
>   https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inst%C3%A2ncia_(classe)

```
// Aqui temos uma classe. Ela ainda não é um objeto.
Class Foo{}

// Aqui criamos um objeto da classe Foo
obj = new Foo

// Repare que não usei o termo "instância" porque esse termo significa "criar". Contudo, não é errado dizer:

// Nova instância de Foo
obj = new Foo
```

Ou seja, o `obj` é um `objeto` instanciado da class `Foo`.

Instância (instanciar/criar) é uma ação. O objeto é uma representação concreta, conforme o wikipedia, *criamos (instanciamos) fisicamente uma representação da classe*.

A definição sobre o que é o objeto também é bem clara e não vejo ambiguidade:

> Em ciência da computação, objeto é uma referência a um local da
>   memória que possui um valor. Um objeto pode ser uma variável, função,
>   ou estrutura de dados. Com a introdução da programação orientada a
>   objetos, a palavra objeto refere-se a uma instância de uma classe.
>
> Em programação orientada a objetos, um objeto passa a existir a partir
>   de um "molde" (classe); a classe define o comportamento do objeto,
>   usando atributos (propriedades) e métodos (ações).
>   https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Importante salientar que ainda na página da Wikipedia traz uma observação sobre o termo instância.

> Em programação orientada a objetos, chama-se instância de uma classe,
>   um objeto cujo comportamento e estado são definidos pela classe.
>   "Instância" é, neste caso, um **anglicismo**, significando "caso" ou
>   "exemplo" (em inglês instance).

Anglicismo: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicismo

Para não complicar o assunto, evitarei comentar sobre [Metaclasse](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclasse) pois foge um pouco do contexto da pergunta. Mas de qualquer forma é bom saber.

O tema é abordado na versão em japonês de "Instância": https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9

> 静的型付けのオブジェクト指向言語では珍しいが、動的型付けのオブジェクト指向言語の多くは、メタクラスをサポートし、クラス自体もオブジェクトとして扱うことができる（クラス・オブジェクト）。クラス・オブジェクトは、端的に言えば変数に束縛できるクラスである。クラス・オブジェクト、インスタンス・オブジェクト双方を変数に束縛した際どちらもオブジェクトとして振る舞い見かけ上区別はつかない。例えばクラス・オブジェクト、インスタンス・オブジェクト双方が
>   readFrom: というメソッドを持っていた場合、どちらも #readFrom:
>   メッセージを送ってやるとエラーも起こさずそれぞれのメソッドを実行する。
>   Objective-CやPythonにおいてはクラス・オブジェクトとインスタンス・オブジェクトの明確な区別が行われている。[3][4]
>   メタクラスがサポートされているシステムでは、クラス・オブジェクトもまた別のクラス（メタクラス）のインスタンスであるということがありうる。この場合「クラス・オブジェクトはインスタンスではない」とは言えないので、注意されたい。

Trata-se de uma breve advertência na qual diz para não confundir instâncias de metaclasses pois em metaclasses as instâncias são também classes.

Como pode ver, podemos sempre complicar ainda mais.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine que classes é como se fosse a planta de uma casa, e ela define a forma da casa no papel, a casa não existe ainda, mas já temos a estrutura para criar uma casa.

Um Objeto é a casa já construída de acordo com a planta. Os dados guardados no objeto são com madeiras ferragens fios e concretos utilizados para compor a casa.

Dentro do objeto temos:

•   **Atributos** é o que define o objeto como cor, tipo de janela, tipo de porta, quantidade de carros etc.

•   **Métodos** é o que define o que a casa fará, exemplo é abrir garagem, abrir janelas, ligar as luzes.

Sendo assim quando você cria um objeto você faz uma instância dele, que é a ação de atribuir as características a uma variável.

[image: Curso Completo de Desenvolvimento Web - Crie 6 projetos]

**Exemplo prático:**

```
//Objeto
class Casa {

    //Atributos

    var $cor;
    var $tipo_de_janela;
    var $tipo_de_porta;


    //Métodos

    function setCor($cor_definido){
        $this->cor = $cor_definido;
    }

    function getCor(){
        return $this->cor;
    }

}

//Instanciando os atributos e métodos do objeto Casa à variável casa número 1, aqui é aonde recebemos os atributos e métodos através do instanciamento no qual poderemos fazer modificações únicas nas variásveis.

$casa_numero_1 = new Casa();

$casa_numero_1->setCor('Laranja<br>');
echo $casa_numero_1->getCor();


$casa_numero_2 = new Casa();

$casa_numero_2->setCor('Branca<br>');
echo $casa_numero_2->getCor();
```

,

**Resumindo: A instância é a AÇÃO de herdar métodos e atributos à variáveis. 
Sendo assim a minha instância casa_numero_1 e casa_numero_2 compartilham o mesmo conjunto de atributos, embora sejam diferentes quanto ao conteúdo desses atributos uma é laranja e outra é branca.**

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor? A forma simplificada da resposta não ficou clara.

Comment: 2 anos depois é um tanto quanto complicado, mas na sua resposta você diz que `casa_numero_1` e `casa_numero_2` são instâncias, mas não seriam objetos? Se "instância" é uma ação, como diz, não tem como variáveis serem instâncias, poderiam ser, no máximo, o resultado dessa ação - que seria o resultado da instância? A pergunta é justamente sobre objeto vs instância e mesmo na resposta você parece misturar os dois conceitos, por isso ficou confusa.

Answer (score -4):

*Exemplo*: Person person = new Person();

**new Person();**  Instância (está alocando espaço em memória).

**person** objeto;