# Um objeto pode ser instanciado?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo a leitura de um código e consta com a seguinte linha

```
$this->controlador = new HomeController();
$this->controlador = new $this->controlador( $this->parametros )
```

A minha dúvida é o seguinte, se está certo este código e o que significa porque nunca tinha ouvido falar que objetos podem ser instanciados

```
class HomeController extends MainController
{

 /**
 * Carrega a página "/views/home/home-view.php"
 */
    public function index() {
 // Título da página
 $this->title = 'Home';

 // Parametros da função
 $parametros = ( func_num_args() >= 1 ) ? func_get_arg(0) : array();
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferença entre Objeto e Instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192233/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos fazer uma demonstração. Observe o codigo a seguir (imagino que faz a mesma coisa que o exemplo mostrado na pergunta):

```
<?php
class Objeto{
    private $atributo = 'Um simples atributo';
    public $parametro = '';
    public function __construct($parametro = 'Automatico'){
        $this->parametro = 'Uma função qualquer chamada por ' . $parametro;     
    }
}

$instancia = new Objeto();
$outraInstancia = new $instancia('Intencional');

var_dump($instancia);
var_dump($outraInstancia);

var_dump($instancia->parametro);
var_dump($outraInstancia->parametro);
```

Esse codigo gera a seguinte saida:

```
/a.php:13:
object(Objeto)[1]
  private 'atributo' => string 'Um simples atributo' (length=19)
  public 'parametro' => string 'Uma função qualquer chamada por Automatico' (length=44)

/a.php:14:
object(Objeto)[2]
  private 'atributo' => string 'Um simples atributo' (length=19)
  public 'parametro' => string 'Uma função qualquer chamada por Intencional' (length=45)

/a.php:16:string 'Uma função qualquer chamada por Automatico' (length=44)

/a.php:17:string 'Uma função qualquer chamada por Intencional' (length=45)
```

Com isso da para chegar a conclusão que `$outraInstancia = new $instancia('Intencional')` é a mesma coisa que `$outraInstancia = new Objeto('Intencional')`

Comment: Verdade. Corrigido.

Answer (score 1):

Foi introduzido um recurso novo na versão do PHP 5.3 que pode ser criado uma instância de um objeto.

> ***A minha dúvida é o seguinte, se está certo este código e o que significa porque nunca tinha ouvido falar que objetos podem ser instanciados***

Sim está correto, mas, a versão que funcional tal recurso é o `PHP` 5.3, ou seja, antes não poderia instânciar dessa forma, mas, a partir dessa versão foi introduzido como um novo recurso.

*Exemplo do própria site* [www.php.com](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php)

```
<?php
class Test
{
    static public function getNew()
    {
        return new static;
    }
}

class Child extends Test
{}

$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;
var_dump($obj1 !== $obj2);

$obj3 = Test::getNew();
var_dump($obj3 instanceof Test);

$obj4 = Child::getNew();
var_dump($obj4 instanceof Child);
?>
```

Saída:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

***Referencia:*** [O básico Classes e Objetos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php)