# Orientação Objeto no C# - Herança

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Em relação a `Orientação Objeto` no `C#`, tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Qual a *diferença* entre a herança de **reutilização de código**, **de construtores**, **de métodos abstratos**, de **superclasses** e de **subclasses**?

Não se refere a duplicata, pois não quero a definição de Herança em orientado objeto. A pergunta é diferente. *Exemplos seriam de ajuda*.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis não se refere a duplicata, a minha pergunta é diferente. Nas soluções sugeridas nem mesmo cita a **reutilização de construtores**, de **superclasses**, e de **subclasses**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os significados de cada conceito já foi perfeitamente explicado nessa pergunta: [Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88546/significado-da-terminologia-orientado-a-objeto)

Mas como você pediu alguns exemplos de como implementar, segue um código muito simples com alguns dos conceitos citados anteriormente

```
#region Classe Abstrata
public abstract class Classe
{
    #region Método Abstrato
    public abstract void tratarValor(double valor);
    #endregion
}
#endregion

#region Classe
public class ClassePai
{       
    #region Construtor
    public ClasseFilha()
    {
        Console.Write("Classe Pai Cconstruida");
    }
    #endregion

    #region Sobrecarga de método
    public void imprimirCumprimento()
    {
        Console.Write("Olá!");
    }

    public void imprimirCumprimento(String nome)
    {
        Console.Write("Olá " + nome);
    }
    #endregion  

    public void imprimirIdentificacao()
    {
        Console.Write("Eu sou a classe Pai");
    }   
}
#endregion 

#region SubClasse
public class ClasseFilha
{   
    #region Construtor          
    private int variavelQualquer;

    public ClasseFilha(int variavelQualquer)
    {
        this.variavelQualquer = variavelQualquer;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Encapsultamento
    private String nomePai;

    public void setNomePai(String nomePai)
    {
        this.nomePai = nomePai;
    }

    public String getNomePai()
    {
        return this.nomePai;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Associação de Classes
    ClasseAssociacao classeAssociada = new ClasseAssociacao();
    #endregion

    #region Sobrescrita de método
    public override void imprimirIdentificacao()
    {
        Console.Write("Eu sou a classe Filha");
    }
    #endregion
}
#endregion

public class ClasseAssociacao
{
    String assosiacao = "Nada";
}
```

> Conforme eu for lembrando mais alguns conceitos eu vou implementando
>   no exemplo