# Numeros primos em C

Tags: c

Eu comecei a programar recentemente e logo me deram o problema de criar um algoritmo para verificar se um numero é primo ou não. Como na época eu ainda estava com certa dificuldade em laços de repetições, criei um algoritmo baseado em if/else para resolver o problema:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a; 
    scanf("%d",&a);
             if(((((a % 2 == 0) and (a != 2))
             or ((a % 3 == 0) and (a != 3)))
             or (((a % 5 == 0) and (a != 5)) 
             or ((a % 7 == 0) and (a != 7)))) )
             {

             }
             else
             {
               printf("%d ", a);
             }


    return 0;
}
```

O algoritmo até verifica se um numero é primo ou não, porem quando a fatoração de um numero é a multiplicação de dois números primos como o 169 (13*13) ou 143 (11*13), o numero também passa como primo.
Utilizei a biblioteca math.h para calcular a raiz do numero e excluir ele quando ele é um quadrado de um numero primo:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    float c, b;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    c = a;
    b = sqrt(c) ;
    if (a == 1)
    {
          printf("o numero 1 nao eh primo");
    }
   if((((((a % 2 == 0) and (a != 2))
   or ((a % 3 == 0) and (a != 3)))
   or (((a % 5 == 0) and (a != 5)) or ((a % 7 == 0) and (a != 7)))) or floor(b) == b ))
    {
          printf("Nao eh primo\n\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d eh primo\n\n\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Porém ainda não consegui resolver números que tem o mesmo caso do 143, a minha duvida é como que posso verificar se um numero é primo ou não **sem** usar laços de repetição.
Obrigado :)

Comment: Não pode e nem de perto o seu programa verifica se o número é primo. Ter dado o resultado que você esperava foi mera coincidência. Você só verifica se o número é múltiplo de 2, 3, 5 e 7 sem que seja um deles. Isso não é verificar se é primo. A definição de ser primo é que o número precisa ser apenas divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo, então você necessariamente terá que criar um laço de repetição para testar todos os possíveis divisores.

Comment: P/ fazer sem laços, tem uma alternativa bem "gambiarra": `if (n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7 || n == 11 ...)` (inclua todos os primos nessa lista, até o maior valor possível para um `int`). Mas por que vc quer fazer sem laços, se com laços [é muito mais fácil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=n%C3%BAmeros+primos+C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom não é código mais elegante que exista ,mas resolve bem o problema com um pouco de recursão.

### Código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ePrimo(int n ,int nn);

int main(void)
{
  int n = 0;
  
  printf("Digite um numero: ");
  scanf("%d" ,&n);
  if (ePrimo(n ,1))
    printf("%d e primo!" ,n);
  else
    printf("%d nao e primo!" ,n);
  
  return 0;
}

bool ePrimo(int n ,int nn)
{
  static int divs = 0;
  
  if (nn > n)
    return n;
  
  if (n % nn == 0)
    divs++;
  
  ePrimo(n ,nn + 1);
  
  if (divs <= 2)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Se necessária alguma explicação ,aqui estou.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que essa seria uma base interessante pro que você quer.

Você não precisa testar todos os valores, pois se até `N/2` não for divisível, a partir daí ele só é divisível por ele próprio.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void chama_primo(int valor);
int checa_primo(int qtd_divisor, int value, int divisor);

int main() {

    int num;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    chama_primo(num);

    return 0;
}

void chama_primo(int valor) {

    if(checa_primo(0, valor, 2)) {
        printf("Número é primo\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Não é primo\n");
    }
}

int checa_primo(int qtd_divisor, int value, int divisor) {

    int aux = qtd_divisor;

    if(qtd_divisor > 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(divisor > (value/2) && qtd_divisor == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(value % divisor == 0) {
        aux++;
    }

    return checa_primo(aux, value, divisor+1);
}
```

Testei até `N = 23` e tudo certo.

Comment: Sua função foi implementada [de maneira pura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/64969). Para testá-la, você não precisa necessariamente passar como argumento um inteiro lido da entrada padrão, apenas um inteiro. Então você poderia facilmente fazer uma validação até o 1.000.000 com apenas 3 linhas a mais

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, confesso que fui desatento. Imaginei que a impossibilidade da utilização de estruturas de repetição fosse uma restrição e não causada por falta de experiência com elas. E o código da minha resposta realmente foi muito mau escrito.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
 

double r;        
int contador,contador2=0,n;

scanf("%d" , &n);
    
 while(n<=0)

{
    
  scanf("%d", &n);

}
        
for (contador=1;n>=contador;contador++)

{
        
r=n%contador;
            
if(r==0)

{
            
contador2++;

}
        
contador++;

}
    
if(contador2==2)

{
    
printf("o número %d é primo", n);

}
   
 else

{
    
printf("o número %d não é primo" , n);

}    
return 0;

}
```