# A diferença entre o valor de um elemento máximo e mínimo de um vetor recursivamente

Tags: c++, recursão

Fiz esse código :

```
int difrecursivo(int *vetor,int tam){
   if(tam == 1)
        return vetor[0];
    else{
        int max = vetor[0];
        if(max < vetor[tam-1])
            max = vetor[tam-1];
        int min = vetor[0];
        if(min > vetor[tam-1])
            min = vetor[tam-1];
        int total = difrecursivo(vetor, tam-1);
        total = max-min;
        if(total < 0)
            return -(total);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Com esse código eu até consegue tirar a diferença entre o maior e o menor elemento de um vetor, mas só quando o tamanho deste vetor é até 5, acima desse valor o código não funciona como deveria.
Tenho que usar recursividade nessa função.
Me ajudem a resolver de modo que sempre tire a diferença entre o valor máximo e minimo de um vetor independente do tamanho.

Comment: Qual a entrada que dá errado? Já tentou fazer um teste de mesa com essa entrada? E por que você inicia o valor de `total` com o resultado da função para _logo em seguida_ sobrescrever esse valor com a diferença, jogando a recursão toda no lixo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muito depende de como será a estratégia de solução. Isso definirá o caminho
recursivo a ser percorrido. Por exemplo, pegue o seguinte algoritmo recursivo
para se calcular o máximo:

1. Se o vetor só tiver 1 elemento, então esse elemento é o máximo
2. Pegue o máximo do vetor excluindo a última posição
3. Compare esse máximo com o último elemento do vetor e retorne o maior

Vou usar de uma função auxiliar que me retorne o máximo entre dois inteiros,
só para constar:

```c
int _max(int a, int b) {
    return a >= b? a: b;
}
```

Então posso facilmente definir a função recursiva desse jeito:

```c
int max_recursiv_1(int *v, int tam) {
    if (tam == 1) {
        return v[0];
    } else {
        return _max(max_recursiv_1(v, tam - 1), v[tam - 1]);
    }
}
```

A estratégia usada aqui é:

- reduza para um problema menor
- resolva o problema menor
- verifique o diferencial do problema original e o menor, computano com a
  resposta do problema menor

Porém, essa não é a única estratégia possível de ser usada. Tem outras também,
com potencial bem interessante. Por exemplo:

- verifique o diferencial do problema original e do menor, obtendo resposta
  parcial
- compute com a resposta parcial previamente conhecida
- passe a resposta parcial para o problema menor
- a resposta do problema menor + resposta parcial é a resposta do problema
  original

Como seria achar o máximo nessa estratégia? Para tal, eu preciso aumentar o
número de parâmetros, incluindo então o parâmetro com a resposta parcial:

```c
int max_recursiv_2(int *v, int tam, int max_parcial) {
    if (tam == 0) {
        return max_parcial;
    } else {
        return max_recursiv_2(v, tam - 1, _max(v[tam - 1], max_parcial));
    }
}
```

Notou como agora a computação é feita a cada passo, não sendo necessário
pós-processamento do retorno da função recursiva? Também tem outra mudança de
comportamento: não é necessário se preocupar com o caso mínimo (no caso, o
caso mínimo era quando só havia um elemento no vetor), mas sim detecção de
"problema vazio".

O que é um problema vazio? Bem, achar o máximo em uma lista de 0 elementos.
Esse problema é vazio, não admite resposta válida a não ser `null` ou outro
indicador de vacuosidade. Isso significa que a resposta parcial obtida nesse
fim da recursão é a repsosta definitiva.

Outra mudança que ocorre é: e como eu faço a chamada da função recursiva? Eu
preciso conhecer como obter uma resposta parcial antes de chamá-la? Isso não
seria uma rotina padronizável?

A resposta é que *sim*, é padronizável. Por exemplo, uma resposta parcial para
o máximo é qualquer elemento da lista. No caso, podemos aproveitar a resposta
parcial e *reduzir* o problema:

```c
int max_recursiv_entrada(int *v, int tam) {
    return max_recursiv_2(v, tam - 1, v[tam - 1]);
}
```

No exemplo, pegamos o último elemento do vetor como resposta parcial e, também,
removemo-lo da lista de processamento.

E por que falei disso tudo? Bem, se tivéssemos uma função que retorne, de algum
jeito, o mínimo e o máximo? Como eu faria um processamento só depois do retorno
da função recursiva?

Posso começar através de um caso base: se só tem 1 elemento, ele é o mínimo e o
máximo. Algo assim:

```py
def min_max_recur_1(vetor, tam):
  if tam == 1:
    return (vetor[0], vetor[0])
  # ...
```

> Os códigos mostrados estão em [python](/questions/tagged/python) como uma sugestão de exercício ao
>   leitor: escrever esses trechos de código em [c](/questions/tagged/c) ou [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). De outras
>   linguagens que também abririam a possibilidade desse exercício, a facilidade
>   de leitura e de expressão também foram motivos decisivos para a escolha
>   de Python.

E como eu faria o passo recursivo? Bem, deveria montar outra tupla de resposta
comparando com o elemento em questão:

```py
def min_max_recur_1(vetor, tam):
  if tam == 1:
    return (vetor[0], vetor[0])
  else:
    resp_menor = min_max_recur_1(vetor, tam - 1)
    return (min(resp_menor[0], vetor[tam - 1]), max(resp_menor[1], vetor[tam - 1]))
```

> Veja sendo executado no [ideone](https://ideone.com/7kPwT1)

Ok, assim funcionou bem. Mas, e se fosse interessante para mim usar a
estratégia de passar a resposta parcial para os próximos passos da recursão?
Eu posso construir a resposta a cada passo e passá-la para baixo. De novo,
faz-se necessário ter um primeiro passo que é o de criação da primeira resposta
parcial, que é um dos elementos ser o máximo *e* o mínimo:

```py
def min_max_entrada(vetor, tam):
  return min_max_recur_2(vetor, tam - 1, vetor[tam - 1], vetor[tam - 1])

def min_max_recur_2(vetor, tam, min_parcial, max_parcial):
  if tam == 0:
    return (min_parcial, max_parcial)
  else:
    return min_max_recur_2(vetor, tam - 1, min(min_parcial, vetor[tam - 1]), max(max_parcial, vetor[tam - 1]))
```

> Veja sendo executado no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Ee5kRH)

Tudo tranquilo até aqui. Conseguimos em uma única recursão achar o máximo e o
mínimo de uma lista. Porém, não queremos esses resultados por si, mas sim uma
computação sobre eles. Que computação? A diferença entre o mínimo e o máximo.
A recursão se preocupa, agora, em buscar essa diferença, enquanto que na saída
global eu desejo aplicar essa função específica. Como no último passo eu já
tenho o resultado da recursão, basta então, no lugar de retornar a resposta
exigida pelo passo recursivo, a função específica sobre essa recursão:

```py
def dif_min_max_entrada(vetor, tam):
  if tam <= 1:
    return 0
  else:
    return dif_min_max_recur(vetor, tam - 1, vetor[tam - 1], vetor[tam - 1])

def dif_min_max_recur(vetor, tam, min_parcial, max_parcial):
  if tam == 0:
    return max_parcial - min_parcial
  else:
    return dif_min_max_recur(vetor, tam - 1, min(min_parcial, vetor[tam - 1]), max(max_parcial, vetor[tam - 1]))
```

> Veja sendo executado no [ideone](https://ideone.com/6MsOLb)

O fato de usarmos as respostas parciais da recursão implica que não precisamos
nos preocupar com algum pós-processamento do retorno. Na estratégia mais direta
da recursão, em que se resolve o caso menor e depois se computa essa resposta
com o diferencial dos casos, a resposta da recursão é obtida a cada passo e
precisa ser processada, então qualquer processamento feito sobre a resposta
final precisa, necessariamente, ser externo a recursão.

Tem alguns cuidados que aproveitei e tomei nessa resposta. O primeiro é que
necessariamente a diferença entre o mínimo e o máximo, quando se tem apenas 1
único elemento, é 0, pois esse elemento sera, ao mesmo tempo, o mínimo **e** o
máximo. O segundo cuidado que eu tomei é que, necessariamente, o máximo será
não menor que o mínimo. Então a diferença entre ambos sempre será um número não
negativo, logo não é necessário checar pela nulidade.

Em contraponto à sua resposta, ela não dá a resposta certa nem mesmo para
vetores de 5 elementos. Pegue o seguinte caso: `{3, 5, 1, 2}`. Qual a resposta
esperada? `4`, que é `5 - 1`. Qual resposta seu algoritmo vai fornecer? `1`,
que é a diferença entre o primeiro e o último elemento.

A sua estratégia foi de tentar encontrar, na função recursiva, a diferença
entre o mínimo e o máximo e então usar o diferencial do problema original para
tentar incrementar a resposta do problema menor. Só que essa estratégia está
condenada, porque a recursão não consegue produzir a resposta que você precisa.

Vamos pegar que, na chamada recursiva, obtemos o resultado `4`, e por algum
motivo essa é a resposta correta para o caso menor. Então, temos que a
diferença entre o caso menor e o caso original é o número `7`. Qual a repsosta
esperada dado isso?

Na real, não dá para saber, justamente porque a resposta obtida pela recursão
não consegue informar o suficiente para, com isso, obter a diferença entre o
mínimo e o máximo. Quais respostas poderiam resultar na diferença `4` entre os
valores extremos? Poderíamos ter `1007` e `1003`, portanto a diferença nova
deveria ser `1000`. Assim como, se fosse `10` e `6`, a resposta deveria
continuar como `4`. Logo, esse parágrafo e o anterior demonstram que é inútil
qualquer tentativa de resolver a recursão, com a resposta da recursão sendo a
diferença entre o mínimo e o máximo, usando essa estratégia.

Agora, voltando ao seu código, como ele irá se comportar para a entrada
`{3, 5, 1, 2}`? Note que ela tem tamanho 4. Conforme eu
[comentei na questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/405905/a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-o-valor-de-um-elemento-m%c3%a1ximo-e-m%c3%adnimo-de-um-vetor-recursivame#comment794867_405905),
na prática a chamada recursiva é ignorada do processamento. E eu sei disso
devido a 2 fatores:

- seu `difrecursivo` é uma [função pura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255557/64969)

  - fácil de verificar pois não há [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/64969)
- o resultado da sua chamada é sobrescrito logo em seguida

Então, se removidos os trechos de código com processamento desperdiçado, ele
fica assim:

```c
int difrecursivo(int *vetor,int tam){
   if(tam == 1)
        return vetor[0];
    else{
        int max = vetor[0];
        if(max < vetor[tam-1])
            max = vetor[tam-1];
        int min = vetor[0];
        if(min > vetor[tam-1])
            min = vetor[tam-1];
        int total; // REMOVIDO = difrecursivo(vetor, tam-1);
        total = max-min;
        if(total < 0)
            return -(total);
        return total;
    }
}
```

Outro detahe também que podemos remover é o segundo `if`. A construção de `min`
e `max` garantem que `min <= max`, logo `total >= 0`. Limpando ainda mais o código:

```c
int difrecursivo(int *vetor,int tam){
   if(tam == 1)
        return vetor[0];
    else{
        int max = vetor[0];
        if(max < vetor[tam-1])
            max = vetor[tam-1];
        int min = vetor[0];
        if(min > vetor[tam-1])
            min = vetor[tam-1];
        int total;
        total = max-min;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Removendo variáveis desnecessárias e ordenando um pouco o código:

```c
int difrecursivo(int *vetor,int tam){
   if(tam == 1)
        return vetor[0];
    else{
        int max, min;
        min = max = vetor[0];

        if(max < vetor[tam-1])
            max = vetor[tam-1];
        if(min > vetor[tam-1])
            min = vetor[tam-1];

        return max-min;
    }
}
```

Assim, fica fácil perceber que só existem 2 valores possíveis para `min` e
para `max`: ou é `vetor[0]` ou é `vetor[tam - 1]`. O resultado seria
equivalente ao seguinte código (para os `_min` e `_max` que defini
anteriormente):

```c
int difrecursivo(int *vetor,int tam){
   if(tam == 1)
        return vetor[0];
    else
        return _max(vetor[0], vetor[tam - 1]) - _min(vetor[0], vetor[tam - 1]);
}
```

Logo, trivialmente eu falo que a resposta para a entrada `{3, 5, 1, 2}` é 1.

A única opção que conheço que poderia resolver seu problema usando recursão de
cabeça seria ter uma função recursiva para determinar o máximo e o mínimo da
lista e outra função, separada, que pega esse valor e tira a diferença. Coisa
semelhante ao da recursão de cauda que eu propus, só que nela a função
não-recursiva se preocupa em tratar a entrada para executar a função recursiva,
enquanto que nesse caso haveria um prepara da saída da função recursiva para
algo útil.