# Como pegar todas as interfaces de um objeto?

Tags: java, reflexão

Estou precisando listar todas as interfaces que um objeto implementa. Pelo que entendi, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```java
Object misterioso;

    ....

misterioso.getClass().getInterfaces();
```

porém isso pegaria apenas as interfaces implementadas **diretamente** pela classe. Ou seja, se a classe desse meu objeto implementasse a interface `I2` que, por sua vez, estende `I1`, essa chamada retornaria apenas `I2`. Foi isso que entendi do [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--) e dos testes que realizei.

Como faço para pegar **todas** as interfaces implementadas por um objeto, incluindo interfaces recursivas (e de superclasses)?

Aceito sugestões com dependências, porém leve em consideração que, no ambiente em que estou trabalhando, só posso ter garantido implementações da JRE até 7 (porém com direito a parte funcional, de `Stream` às interfaces funcionais aos `Optional`s), não tenho acesso a criação de `Proxy` sobre as interfaces e que boa parte das dependências disponíveis são incompatíveis com a ferramenta em que o código irá rodar.

Comment: Quem deu o negativo poderia me explicar como posso melhorar a questão? A ponto de ser digno do seu positivo se possível =3

Comment: Posso estar viajando, mas não dá pra ir percorrendo as superclasses até `Object` e pegando as interfaces implementadas por cada uma?

Comment: Acho que a reflexão deva se feita de maneira recursiva para cada interface obtida diretamente. ps: apertei +1, a pergunta é boa.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, muito obrigado =D Aproveitando (cc Piovezan), consegui chegar em algo que eu acredite ser a resposta, mas estou fazendo mais testes e com preguiça de uma demonstração formal baseado [nessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406171/64969). A resposta tem nada a ver com Java nem reflexão, mas sobre recursão, conforme a dica de vocês 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Precisa ser implementado um processo recursivo para a busca das implementações mais internas, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public static ArrayList<String> SetInterfaces(Class<?>[] interfaces,
                                              ArrayList<String> items)
{        
    for (Class<?> intf : interfaces) {
        items.add(intf.getName());
        SetInterfaces(intf.getInterfaces(), items);
    }
    return items;
}
```

e para utilizar esse código:

```
Car car = new Car();
Class<?>[] interfaces = car.getClass().getInterfaces();
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
SetInterfaces(interfaces, items)
        .forEach((item) -> {
             System.out.println(item);
         });
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/yb05Up)

No exemplo só é mostrado o nome da classe, dando um exemplo da saída das buscas mais internas de `interfaces` implementadas

---

O usuário não tinha mencionado o uso de herança mas, indagou isso se tivesse heranças até chegar a todas as `interfaces` implementadas, seguindo praticamente a  mesma lógica:

```
public static Set<String> SetInterfaces(Class<?> aClass,
                                          Set<String> items)
{           
    for (Class<?> intf : aClass.getInterfaces()) {
        items.add(intf.getName()); 
        SetInterfaces(intf, items);            
    }
    if (aClass.isInterface() == false && aClass.getSuperclass() != null) {
        SetInterfaces(aClass.getSuperclass(), items);
    }        
    return items;
}
```

e

```
OnibusBiTrem oni = new OnibusBiTrem();
Class<?> classes = oni.getClass(); 
Set<String> items = new HashSet<>() ;        
SetInterfaces(classes, items)
            .forEach((item) -> {
                 System.out.println(item);
             });
```

[Exemplo OnLine](https://ideone.com/xPNeid)

Comment: Faltou só navegar na superclasse. Eu sei que não especifiquei, mas vai navegar/listar múltiplas vezes a mesma interface se por acaso duas interfaces implementarem a mesma superinterface. A dupla listagem se resolve usando `Set` ou suas variações, já evitar a dupla navegação poderia ser simplesmente perguntado à coleção se ela já tem o elemento (`contains`).

Comment: Mais é como você mesmo relatou @JeffersonQuesado falta informações e o que eu propus a você é um exemplo simples, sem informações a mais e navegar na super classe como assim se o dados vem de um super classe? não entendi mesmo essa observação

Comment: imagina que eu tenho a classe `Bus`, que estende de `Car` e implementa `HasPassengers`, e a classe `OnibusBiTrem`, que estende de `Bus` e implementa a interface `IMultiplosVagoes`. Se `HasPassengers` e `IMultiolosVagoes` não estenderem nenhuma interface, eu deveria obtê-las e também a todas as interfaces de `Car` quando eu fosse atrás das interfaces de `new OnibusBiTrem()`. De toda sorte, é trivial alterar seu código para fazer essa navegação, por isso que já marquei como a resposta adequada

Comment: Eu acho que é isso que você quer, mudou um pouco mas, é a mesma idéia @JeffersonQuesado

Answer (score 4):

> Essa resposta começou a ser redigida antes da [resposta do Virgilio Novic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406566/64969).
>
> Minha abordagem tem uma visão diferente, com uma construção de conhecimento que considero válida compartilhar, mas o código obtido
>   continua sendo mais ou menos o do Virgilio Norvig.

Esse é um problema recursivo (conforme indicado por Piovezam e Augusto Vasques nos comentários). Posso reduzi-lo a uma busca em um grafo direcionado acíclico.

Nesse grafo, tenho 3 tipos de nós:

- nó de objeto (a entrada, não interessa para o resultado final)
- nós de classe (não interessa para o resultado final)
- nós de interface (interessa para o resultado final)

A questão, então, se torna em como, a partir do nó de objeto, quais nós de interface eu consigo alcançar. Uma coisa interessante na estrutura desse grafo é a seguinte:

- o grafo é finito, sempre
- o nó de entrada tem apenas uma aresta, que vai para um nó de classe (identificado por `getClass()`)
- o nó de classe pode apontar para outro nó de classe (identificado por `getSuperclass()`), e também pode apontar para diversos nós de interface (identificado por `getInterfaces()`)
- o nó de interface pode apontar para diversos nós de interface (identificado por `getInterfaces()`)

Como é acíclico e finito, eu posso navegá-lo em profundidade sem problemas. Uma ideia bem por cima do como eu percorro esse grafo é a seguinte:

```
def percorre_grafo(nodo):
  se nodo é objeto:
    percorre_grafo(nodo.getClass())
  se nodo é de classe:
    para iface em nogo.getInterfaces():
      percorre_grafo(iface)
    se nodo.getSuperclass() != null:
      percorre_grafo(nodo.getSuperclass)
  se nodo é interface:
    # faz algo com o nodo em questão
    para iface em nogo.getInterfaces():
      percorre_grafo(iface)
```

Porém, posso deixar blocos de códigos com preocupações menores. Por exemplo, um bloco
para ser o *front*, recebendo o objeto em questão, outro para percorrer as classes/superclasses desse objeto
e finalmente um último bloco que percorre recursivamente as interfaces:

```
def percorre_grafo__front(nodo):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "objeto"
  # só tem uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  percorre_grafo__classe(nodo.getClass())

def percorre_grafo__classe(nodo):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "classe"
  # pode ter uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  # podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  se nodo.getSuperclass() != null:
    percorre_grafo__classe(nodo.getSuperclass())
  percorre_grafo__interface(iface) para iface em nodo.getInterfaces()

def percorre_grafo__interface(nodo):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "interface"
  # podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  # faz algo com o nodo em questão
  percorre_grafo__interface(iface) para iface em nodo.getInterfaces()
```

Eu ainda posso remover a recursão da função `percorre_grafo__classe`, porque ela é uma função recursiva
trivial. Fica assim o desenrolar iterativo dela:

```
def percorre_grafo__classe(nodo):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "classe"
  # pode ter uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  # podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  iter = nodo
  enquanto iter != null:
    percorre_grafo__interface(iface) para iface em iter.getInterfaces()
    iter = iter.getSuperclass()
```

Nessa estratégia eu passo por todos os nós alcançáveis a partir do objeto em questão, inclusive repetindo a mesma interface diversas vezes.
Se eu admitir que a parte da recursão é *alcançar os nós*, então posso passar para o passo recursivo a "resposta" sendo construída,
numa estratégia semelhante a que usei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406171/64969) para descobrir
a diferença entre o maior e o menor elemento de uma lista de maneira recursiva. O **fazer algo com o nodo em questão** é
adicionar no conjunto. Se o nodo já estava previamente no conjunto, significa que eu já tinha passado por ele, então não
é necessário fazer a chamada recursiva.

Assumindo isso como a estratégia, e levando em consideração a função `percorre_grafo__classe` como sendo o ponto de entrada
que prepara a função para a chamada recursiva, temos então o seguinte algoritmo:

```
def percorre_grafo__front(nodo):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "objeto"
  # só tem uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  percorre_grafo__classe(nodo.getClass())

def percorre_grafo__classe(nodo):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "classe"
  # pode ter uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  # podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  conjunto_interfaces = new Set()
  iter = nodo
  enquanto iter != null:
    percorre_grafo__interface(iface, conjunto_interfaces) para iface em iter.getInterfaces()
    iter = iter.getSuperclass()

def percorre_grafo__interface(nodo, conjunto_interfaces):
  # garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "interface"
  # podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  se conjunto_interfaces não contém nodo:
    conjunto_interfaces.add(nodo)
    percorre_grafo__interface(iface) para iface em nodo.getInterfaces()
```

E em Java, como seria isso?

```java
HashSet<Class<?>> percorre_grafo__front(Object nodo) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "objeto"
  // só tem uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"

  return percorre_grafo__classe(nodo.getClass());
}

HashSet<Class<?>> percorre_grafo__classe(Class<?> nodo) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "classe"
  // pode ter uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  // podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  HashSet<Class<?>> conjunto_interfaces = new HashSet<>();

  Class<?> iter = nodo;
  while (iter != null) {
    Stream.of(iter.getInterfaces()).forEach(iface -> percorre_grafo__interface(iface, conjunto_interfaces));
    iter = iter.getSuperclass();
  }
  return conjunto_interfaces;
}

void percorre_grafo__interface(Class<?> nodo, HashSet<Class<?>> conjunto_interfaces) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "interface"
  // podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  if (conjunto_interfaces.add(nodo)) {
    Stream.of(nodo.getInterfaces()).forEach(iface -> percorre_grafo__interface(iface, conjunto_interfaces));
  }
}
```

Usando uma padronização de nomes/código um pouco mais Java:

```java
public HashSet<Class<?>> percorreGrafo(Object obj) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "objeto"
  // só tem uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"

  return percorreGrafo__classe(obj.getClass());
}

private HashSet<Class<?>> percorreGrafo__classe(Class<?> clazz) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "classe"
  // pode ter uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  // podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  HashSet<Class<?>> interfaces = new HashSet<>();
  for (Class<?> iter = clazz; iter != null; iter = iter.getSuperclass()) {
    Stream.of(iter.getInterfaces()).forEach(iface -> percorreGrafo__interface(iface, interfaces));
  }
  return interfaces;
}

private void percorreGrafo__interface(Class<?> clazz, HashSet<Class<?>> interfaces) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "interface"
  // podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  if (interfaces.add(clazz)) {
    Stream.of(clazz.getInterfaces()).forEach(iface -> percorreGrafo__interface(iface, interfaces));
  }
}
```

Removendo `Stream`:

```java
public HashSet<Class<?>> percorreGrafo(Object obj) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "objeto"
  // só tem uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"

  return percorreGrafo__classe(obj.getClass());
}

private HashSet<Class<?>> percorreGrafo__classe(Class<?> clazz) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "classe"
  // pode ter uma aresta que aponta para um nó do tipo "classe"
  // podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  HashSet<Class<?>> interfaces = new HashSet<>();
  for (Class<?> iter = clazz; iter != null; iter = iter.getSuperclass()) {
    for (Class<?> iface: iter.getInterfaces()) {
      percorreGrafo__interface(iface, interfaces);
    }
  }
  return interfaces;
}

private void percorreGrafo__interface(Class<?> clazz, HashSet<Class<?>> interfaces) {
  // garanto aqui que nodo é do tipo "interface"
  // podem ter diversas arestas que apontam para nós do tipo "interface"

  if (interfaces.add(clazz)) {
    for (Class<?> iface: clazz.getInterfaces()) {
      percorreGrafo__interface(iface, interfaces);
    }
  }
}
```

Note que o método `Set.add(E e)` retorna verdadeiro caso não tenha ainda o elemento `e`, e
ainda por cima o adicionano conjunto. Caso `e` já exista, retorna falso. Logo, adicionar
um nó no conjunto de interfaces visitadas já está fazendo ao mesmo tempo a verificação
de que o elemento está no conjunto. Então, se `interfaces.add(clazz)` retornar `true`, isso
significa que `clazz` ainda não estava no conjunto e que foi adicionado.

---

Como posso ter tanta certeza da construção desses grafos? Ora, lendo a documentação.

Em primeiro lugar, a linguagem **não faz** herança múltipla (gramática descrita na [JLS 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)). Logo, se eu estiver herdando de alguma classe (ps: sempre está), não posso herdar de nenhuma outra. Logo, só posse ter, no máximo, uma superclasse.

Está documentado em Java que toda classe herda de `Object`, direta ou indiretamente ([JLS 4.3.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)). E também está documentado que `Object.class.getSuperclass()` retorna `null` ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--)).

Também tem na especificação da linguagem Java que uma interface não pode se implementar ciclicamente ([JLS 12.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2.1)). Logo, é impossível sair de uma interface e, através de `getInterfaces()`, chegar nela de novo. Eu **sempre** chegarei em uma interface que não estende nenhuma outra, uma interface que é fim de linha.

---

Note que o código do Virgilio Novic faz a mesma coisa que o desta resposta, porém em um método só, e retorna o conjunto adequado de interfaces (apesar de por ventura passar por uma dessas interfaces mais de uma vez).