# Qual a diferença entre as funções map() e flatMap() do Java 8?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8, programação-funcional

Qual a diferença entre as funções `map()` e `flatMap()` disponibilizadas pela API *stream* do Java 8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vamos começar do significado das palavras?

- [*flat*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/flat#Adjetivo_2): achatado, plano

Então, o `flatMap` vai mapear e aplanar. O que isso quer dizer? Antes de responder, me permita dar uma volta pra falar de manipulação desses fluxos de dados.

Uma das características que tornam mais interessantes o uso de *streams* é manipular os elementos individuais delas, sem precisar se preocupar com o como os dados chegam. No caso do `map`, eu pego um elemento e transformo em outro elemento. Normalmente você o faz para mudar um tipo para outro ou faz uma operação sobre ele. Mas, as vezes, um único elemento original pode ser mapeado em diversos outros elementos, e você precisa trabalhar em cima desses elementos derivados.

Por exemplo: eu tenho uma classe chamada `CategoriaCliente`, que dentro dela uma lista de `TipoCliente`, e dentro de `TipoCliente` tenho uma lista de `SegmentacaoCliente`. Eu preciso exibir todas as segmentações de clientes para uma determinada categoria. Como você faria?

De modo imperativo, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```java
// class CategoriaCliente

public Set<SegmentacaoCliente> getSegmentacoesNavegaveis() {
  Set<SegmentacaoCliente> segmentacoes = new HashSet<>();

  for (TipoCliente tipo: tiposCliente) {
    for (CategoriaCliente categoria: tipo.getCategoriasCliente()) {
      segmentacoes.add(categoria);
    }
  }

  return segmentacoes;
}
```

De maneira funcional, a ideia seria o seguinte:

1. pego uma *stream* dos meus `tiposCliente`
2. transformo um `TipoCliente` em diversos `CategoriaCliente`
3. coleto esse fluxo em um conjunto

O passo 2. implica que estou usando um elemento atômico (`TipoCliente`) e transformando em diversos outros. Fica assim a implementação:

```java
// class CategoriaCliente

public Set<SegmentacaoCliente> getSegmentacoesNavegaveis() {
  return tiposCliente.stream()
      .flatMap(tipo -> tipo.getCategoriasCliente().stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Tenho um outro caso interessante aqui com `flatMap`: eu preciso saber, em um pedido, quanto de cada família está sendo vendido. A estrutura dos objetos não é complicada: um pedido tem itens, cada item tem um produto, cada produto tem uma família, uma família pode ter uma família mãe ou ser a família raiz (não existem ciclos de famílias, apenas árvores de família).

Em família, já existe um método chamado `getFamiliasAncestrais()`, que pega ela mesma e toda a sua linhagem de antecessoras até a raiz. O código desse resgate é tedioso, então não vale nem a pena colocar seu funcionamento interno.

Então, começamos com o pedido. Funcionalmente, faria o seguinte:

1. pego os itens
2. mapeio o item para uma coleção de pares, os pares compostos por a família e sua quantidade de venda
3. coleto em um agrupamento onde a chave é a família que está no par e o valor é a soma das quantidades de vendas

Ficou assim o código:

```java
Map<FamiliaProduto, BigDecimal> mapQtItensFamilias = pedido.getItensPedido().stream()
    .flatMap(
       ip -> ip.getProduto().getFamilia().getFamiliasAncestrais()
                 .stream()
                 .map(f -> Pair.getPair(f, ip.getQtItem()))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::left, HashMap::new, BigDecimalUtils.summing(Pair::right)));
```

> O código que estou colocando aqui está com deveras simplificações, porque o alvo onde meu código vai de fato ser rodado (Java tradicional em servidor, Android, GWT e TotalCross) tem suas limitações específicas.
>
> No caso do TotalCross, não há suporte a métodos lambda, mas eu contorno isso usando o Retrolambda. Também não tenho fornecido acesso a *stream* do Java 8, mas isso também não me limita porque [fiz uma biblioteca de "compatibilidade"](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox). Por exemplo, no lugar de usar `pedido.getItensPedido().stream()` eu preciso usar `new Stream<>(pedido.getItensPedido())`, mas o uso geral após a criação da *stream* é o mesmo
>
> Outro problema que enfrento é que o GWT e o Java rodando no servidor usam `java.math.BigDecimal`, que não é/era reconhecida facilmente pelo TotalCross, que usa `totalcross.util.BigDecimal` (inclusive os métodos `BigDecimal.remainder(BigDecimal)` tem retornos diferentes), então precisei criar uma classe para envelopar e isolar esses ambientes, trabalhando em cima de suas classes bases corretas. Por isso que usei no coletor o meu próprio `BigDecimalUtils.<T>summing(Function<T,BigDecimal>)`, para assim trabalhar em cima de minha própria classe.

De modo imperativo (usando as facilidades do Java 8), seria algo assim:

```java
Map<FamiliaProduto, BigDecimal> mapQtItensFamilias = new HashMap<>();
for (ItemPedido ip: pedido.getItensPedido()) {
  BigDecimal qtItem = ip.getQtItem();
  for (FamiliaProduto fp: ip.getProduto().getFamilia().getFamiliasAncestrais()) {
    mapQtItensFamilias.merge(fp, qtItem, BigDecimal::add);
  }
}
```

Agora, e se você não tivesse as facilidades do Java 8?

```java
Map<FamiliaProduto, BigDecimal> mapQtItensFamilias = new HashMap<>();
for (ItemPedido ip: pedido.getItensPedido()) {
  BigDecimal qtItem = ip.getQtItem();
  for (FamiliaProduto fp: ip.getProduto().getFamilia().getFamiliasAncestrais()) {
    BigDecimal old = mapQtItensFamilias.get(fp);
    if (old != null) {
      mapQtItensFamilias.put(fp, old.add(qtItem));
    } else {
      mapQtItensFamilias.put(fp, qtItem);
    }
  }
}
```

Um outro caso interessante: quando eu precisei fazer um injetor de dependências no TotalCross (o projeto estava passando por mudanças mais rápidas do que seríamos capaz de continuar "injetando na mão" mantendo a sanidade mental).

> Fiz algumas perguntas [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406558/64969) [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408497/64969) [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408621/64969) que colaboraram com a implementação desse injetor

Basicamente, a ideia desse injetor era o seguinte: eu registro nele objetos com diversos `getters`. Cada um desses `getters` (se passar em algum critério arbitrário que posso passar no momento do registro) se comporta semelhante a um método com a anotação `@Bean` de um objeto anotado com `@Configuration` do Spring, mas eu não posso nomeá-los, e os identifico unicamente pelas suas interfaces. Então, tendo todos esses objetos criados, verifico seus `setters` para ver quais são as interfaces que eles dependem (posso deixar a dependência aberta, como se fosse um [`@Autowired(required = false)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html#required--)).

Depois de criar todos os objetos e mapear corretamente seus `setters`, eu faço o povoamento. O coração desse povoamento é mapear as interfaces aos objetos que as implementam. Após eu completar todo o registro dos meus "beans" e antes de fazer a injeção, eu faço essa normalização de apontar `interface -> [obj_impl1 obj_impl2..]`:

```java
// class InjetorDependencias
  ...

  private ArrayList<MetadataInjection> managedBeans = new ArrayList<>();
  private boolean normalized = false;
  private Map<Class<?>, List<Pair<Object, Class<?>>>> metadataMultimap;

  ...

  private void normalize() {
    if (!this.normalized) {
      metadataMultimap = managedBeans.stream().flatMap(this::explodeMetadata).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getValue()));
      this.normalized = true;
    }
  }

  private Stream<Pair<Object, Class<?>>> explodeMetadata(MetadataInjection metadata) {
    Object obj = metadata.getObj();
    
    return metadata.getIfaces().stream().map(iface -> Pair.getPair(obj, iface));
  }

  ...
}
```

Note aqui o uso do `flatMap` para fazer o acompanhamento dos objetos e suas diversas classes.

Se isso fosse feito sem *streams*, porém com direito a Java 8:

```java
// class InjetorDependencias
  ...

  private ArrayList<MetadataInjection> managedBeans = new ArrayList<>();
  private boolean normalized = false;
  private Map<Class<?>, List<Pair<Object, Class<?>>>> metadataMultimap;

  ...

  private void normalize() {
    if (!this.normalized) {
      metadataMultimap = new HashMap<>();
      for (MetadataInjection bean: managedBeans) {
        Object obj = bean.getObj();
        for (Class<?> iface: bean.getIfaces()) {
          metadataMultimap.compute(iface, (k, listaObjetos) -> {
            if (listaObjetos == null) {
              listaObjetos = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            listaObjetos.add(obj);
            return listaObjetos;
          });
        }
      }
      this.normalized = true;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Agora sem as facilidades do Java 8:

```java
// class InjetorDependencias
  ...

  private ArrayList<MetadataInjection> managedBeans = new ArrayList<>();
  private boolean normalized = false;
  private Map<Class<?>, List<Pair<Object, Class<?>>>> metadataMultimap;

  ...

  private void normalize() {
    if (!this.normalized) {
      metadataMultimap = new HashMap<>();
      for (MetadataInjection bean: managedBeans) {
        Object obj = bean.getObj();
        for (Class<?> iface: bean.getIfaces()) {
          List<Object> listaObjetos = metadataMultimap.get(iface);
          if (listaObjetos == null) {
            listaObjetos = new ArrayList<>();
            metadataMultimap.put(iface, listaObjetos);
          }
          listaObjetos.add(obj);
        }
      }
      this.normalized = true;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Para terminar, tem um último caso interessante em que utilizo `flatMap`. Eu tenho um mapa de nome de tabela para uma tripla (`Map<String, Collection<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>>>`). Essa tripla consiste de: chave, status (ok ou falha) e mensagem. Preciso passar pro banco essas informações, porém o meu driver de JDBC do SQL Server tem uma limitação de parâmetros preparados. Se não me engano era em torno de 700 ou 600 e pouco na época em que escrevi, ou então eu confundi com a documentação de outro driver que tinha esse tamanho na limitação. Além de cada valor da tripla, também necessito, preciso informar ao banco o nome da tabela relacionada a cada tripla.

Para tratar dessas informações já existia uma *procedure* no banco que recebe uma variável tabular com essas informações. O que foi que eu fiz, para usar o máximo possível de proveito:

- criei uma CTE para inserir as informações das triplas através de parâmetros de `PreparedStatement`
- dessa CTE, fiz uma inserção em uma variável tabular junto com o a chave do mapeamento
- passei essa variável para a *procedure*

Como já estava usando o `MyBatis` em diversos pontos do sistema e ele não se mostrou um empecilho, usei-o para fazer a montagem da minha `PreparedStatement` para fazer iterações.

Dito isso, fiz o seguinte:

- peguei cada 20 triplas e guardei em uma sublista
- associei o nome de cada tabela (chave do mapeamento) com cada sublista
- executei minha função de registro (`ackMapper.registraAck`) passando a tabela e a sublista

O código ficou isso:

```java
// import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

Map<String, Collection<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>>> tabelasAcks = contentHandler.getResponseMap();

tabelasAcks.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> Lists.partition(e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()), 20).stream().map(l -> ImmutablePair.of(e.getKey(), l)))
    .forEach(sublistaPair -> ackMapper.registraAck(sublistaPair.getLeft(), sublistaPair.getRight()));
```

> Sim, se o retorno de `contentHandler.getResponseMap` fosse `Map<String, List<...>>` eu não precisava ter feito `e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())`, seria simplesmente `e.getValue()`, mas não lembro o motivo de retornar `Collection<...>` no lugar de `List<...>`

Fazendo isso de modo imperativo:

```java
// import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

Map<String, Collection<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>>> tabelasAcks = contentHandler.getResponseMap();

for (EntrySet<String, Collection<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>>> e: tabelasAcks.entrySet()) {
  String tableName = e.getKey();
  for (List<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>> sublista: Lists.partition(new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()), 20)) {
    ackMapper.registraAck(tableName, sublista);
  }
}
```

Se não tivesse o `com.google.common.collect.Lists` do meu lado:

```java
Map<String, Collection<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>>> tabelasAcks = contentHandler.getResponseMap();

for (EntrySet<String, Collection<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>>> e: tabelasAcks.entrySet()) {
  List<ImmutableTriple<String, String, String>> lista = new ArrayList<>();
  String tableName = e.getKey();
  int i = 0;
  for (ImmutableTriple<String, String, String> tripla: e.getValue()) {
    i++;
    lista.add(tripla);
    if (i == 20) {
      i = 0;
      ackMapper.registraAck(tableName, lista);
      lista.clear();
    }
  }
  if (i > 0) {
    ackMapper.registraAck(tableName, lista);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Ambas pegam os elementos de um *stream* de dados (geralmente uma solução como *array* ou `ArrayList`) e cada elemento terá uma ação a ser definida em seguida.

A diferença que `flatMap()` consegue fazer isso em *streams* que possuem dimensões (ele achata os dados para ficar linear), então cada elementos daquela coleção de dados será usado independente de ele estar aninhado nessa coleção. Quando você tem dados que estão de forma linear nunca é preciso usá-la.

Vamos dizer que você tenha uma lista de listas, a função `map()` pegaria as listas internas, mas o que você quer é os elementos dessas listas, então só `flatMap()` resolve.

Outro exemplo é ter uma lista de *strings* e você quer os caracteres. Enquanto `map()` pegara os textos um por um, `flatMap()` pegaria os caracteres.

Exemplo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> listOfListofInts = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6), Arrays.asList( 7, 8, 9));
        System.out.println(listOfListofInts.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println(listOfListofInts.stream().map(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SPq9VL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FlatMapjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/FlatMap.java).